# NoSuchMethodError using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I haven't changed its pom.xml for this project, but when I started the project recently, it reported this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.
Seeing the error, it seems that it can't find the interface method I wrote.

```
2020-07-21 10:23:05.212 ERROR [main] ApiDescriptionReader::read[#87] : Skipping process path[/projects], method[addProject] as it has an error.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.equalsTypeAndSubtype(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)Z
    at springfox.documentation.builders.BodyParameterSpecificationProvider.lambda$create$0(BodyParameterSpecificationProvider.java:37)
... ...
```

I tried mvn clean install, it still doesn't work. This is the io.springfox dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-webflux:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Comment: [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile

Did you check if MimeType class is available in 5.0.7.RELEASE



I can see in my codebase its available in 5.2.6, 5.2.7 versions

Comment: yes, it seems like versioning problems! Please check the Spring  version!

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` and make sure you are using a compatible swagger version (you are using a quite recent one and a snapshot as well).

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation this method exists since spring 5.1.4

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MimeType.html#equalsTypeAndSubtype-org.springframework.util.MimeType-

You can update the version of spring that you use or decrease the version of spring-fox